# How to find the exponential of a number?

Tags: python

What is the easiest/most optimal way of finding the exponential of a number, say `x`, in Python? i.e. how can I implement `e^x`?

Comment: That's just "finding the exponential", not finding the "exponential *of a function*".

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most optimal way to do `e^x` in Python is:

```py
from math import exp

print(exp(4))
```

**Output**

```py
>>> 54.598150033144236
```

Comment: Just curios how this differ from the other answer?

Comment: Import only `exp` function instead of import the whole `math` module

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `math.exp()` function from the `math` module ([read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)).

```py
>>> import math
>>> x = 4
>>> print(math.exp(x))
54.598150033144236
```

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer, but perhaps this question could be deleted rather than answered.